# How to have kids with another player in Minecraft Comes Alive?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-comes-alive

I'm playing Minecraft Comes Alive with my boyfriend and we're already married (with `/mca proposal`) but, how can we have kids?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do `/mca procreate < PlayerName >`